# Would a large array be stored in memory entirely in Java?

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-management

I'm coding a small app for Android and I'm worried about memory consumption.

I will be initializing an array with a lot of string variables  inside the constructor of an object. Possibly thousands of string variables each a paragraph long. But I'm worried all of this will be stored in memory.

The app will display a single array variable at a time. Would this affect the performance of the app?  I want the app to load a single string variable at a time to the memory.

Comment: Yes, arrays are stored in memory.  Where else are you going to store them?  The filesystem?  That's going to be much much slower to access.

Comment: If you are going to work with only one variable at a time, why don't you store the String array in a database, index it and fetch as needed? It won't be as fast but you won't have to worry about the memory use.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays will be stored in memory. The other option would be to write them to disk and read them off disk when needed, which is extremely slow. Without know the structure or purpose of your app, I would recommend trying to store the data in a way that it would only be added to memory when it was needed.

Answer (score 1):

> Would a large array be stored in memory entirely in Java?

Yes.

> I will be initializing an array with a lot of string variables inside
>   the constructor of an object. Possibly thousands of string variables
>   each a paragraph long

This is a very bad idea.

> Would this affect the performance of the app?

Yes, especially on low-end devices with limited hardware resources.

It's hard to suggest anything specific just based on the information you provided, by you definitely need to have some way of caching the data and then loading it on demand instead of keeping huge arrays in device's memory (apart from performance issues and possible UI impact, the system may simply kill you app if it runs out of memory, which can happen pretty fast on low-end devices).

> want the app to load a single string variable at a time to the memory

This is a bit of an overkill and would also significantly slow down your data access, since the RAM is the fastest storage your app has available.